# Modify OpenLayers 3 clustering

Tags: openlayers, clustering

How to add clustering strategy in OpenLayers 3 like OpenLayers 2?

anyone have example?

I want to clustering only the feature with have same class and every clustering I want give a overlay..

Must I overwrite clustersource.js or I can use another method?

Comment: Can you edit your question to show what you have tried, perhaps you can show how the clustering stagegy for OL2 works for you and how trying to something similar in OL fails, or doesn't work as expected.  Images of out puts would be good.  What is clustersource.js please explain.